# Transforming a list into a tree using a relation

Tags: algorithm

I have a flat list of polygons in random order. I have an inside() (or encloses()) function than returns a boolean that tells me if a polygon is inside/encloses another (but I can have nested polygons). So assuming the list `[P1, P2, .. P9]` and these tests that return true:

```
P1 inside P3
P2 inside P3
P5 inside P3
P6 inside P3
P7 inside P3
P1 inside P2
P5 inside P2
P7 inside P2
P5 inside P1
P7 inside P1
P8 inside P9
```

I want to obtain that tree

```
├── P3
│   ├── P2
│   │   └── P1
│   │       ├── P5
│   │       └── P7
│   └── P6
├── P4
└── P9
    └── P8
```

There are obvious brute force solutions:

```
def makeTree(polygons):
    topLevel=[]
    for s in polygons:
        for other in polygons:
            if s is other:
                continue
            if other.encloses(s):
                other.children.append(s)
                break
        else:
            topLevel.append(s)
    for s in topLevel:
        s.children=makeTree(s.children)
    return topLevel
```

but this one is O(n²) and I'm trying to avoid calling inside() too many times (I can have several hundred polygons).

Any clever ideas?

Comment: The polygons are unique?

Comment: Yes, you can assume than there are no identical polynoms

Comment: Looks like [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) for me.